# Finding named functions in built Vue app files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, commonjs, umd

I have a completed Vue app that I am trying to 'build' and then trying to use in another app as an import.

In main.js

```
export function appInit(options = {}){
  new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    store,
    router
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
```

I also tried

```
export default function appInit(....)
```

I then build the project using a vue.config.js file using this command.

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myApp
```

This generates a /dist folder with

```
myApp.common.js
myApp.common.js.map
myApp.umd.js
myApp.umd.js.map
myApp.umd.min.js
myApp.umd.min.js.map
```

I have tried the common.js file and the umd.min.js file in another app and imported them like this.

```
import MyApp from './js/myApp.common.js'
//or
import MyApp from './js/myApp.umd.min.js'
//or
import MyApp from './js/myApp.common'
//or
import MyApp from './js/myApp.umd.min'
```

Then underneath I call.

```
MyApp.appInit()
```

I even tried

```
MyApp()
```

In every case, this is the error..

```
"export 'appInit' was not found in './js/myApp.common.js'
```

or in any other of the files I tried.

Furthermore, I searched myApp.common.js and myApp.umd.min.js looking for the string 'appInit'. After all, that IS the function name I need to call. It does not exist in either file. Of course.

Is that the problem, that named exports do not work on obfuscated files? What am I missing here?

---

I have even tried this..

I created var with just the Vue object

```
var MyApp = new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  store,
  router
})
```

Then an export function that returns it

```
export function appInit(){
  return MyApp
}
```

In my test app I am importing the common.js build file with:

```
import appInit from './js/myApp.common'
```

Then I did

```
appInit.$mount('#app')
```

appInit should be the function I exported.

```
export 'default' (imported as 'appInit') was not found in './js/myApp.comm
on'
```

Comment: Where is main.js used? That you can't find the function suggests that it wasn't included into the build. It's named export and not default, so it couldn't be imported as `import MyApp from` any way.

Comment: @EstusFlask so should import  main.js first then other js files?, in simple should use as nmp and that will work?

Comment: main.js is in the /src folder in a Vue app. It is THE entry point for the app. It tyically creates a new Vue object and sets your other stuff, like the store, or router etc. 


It would be nuts if the vue.config.js I am using for the build did not include main.js.. I will check but but I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: This turned out to be such a simple fix I am surprised nobody spotted it. 

    import { appInit } from.. . . . . 

Curly bracers!!!